# function that counts unique characters for even-lengthed strings in a list? (List Comprehension)

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I want to make a function that first filters through a list and retrieves values of even length. Then, it counts the unique characters in each evenly-lengthed value then returns the amount as a list of numbers. The function is not case-sensitive, so it counts lower and upper case characters as the same. To specify, however, I would like to write this function **using list comprehension without using lambda or imports. I would also like to write it without using for-loops outside of the list comprehension.**

for example `unique_evens([‘tifa’, ‘cloud’, ‘barret’])` should return `[4, 5]`. This is because the function only counts the unique characters in ‘tifa’ and ‘barret’ and skips over ‘cloud’ because the word is 5 characters long.

**What I've tried:**

```
def unique_even(names):
    even_numbered_names = []
    numbers = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if len(names[i])%2 == 0:
            even_numbered_names.append(names[i])
    for i in range(len(even_numbered_names)):
        numbers.append(len(set(even_numbered_names[i])))
    return numbers
```

when `unique_even(['Cloud','Tifa','Barret'])` is inputted into the function, it returns `[4,5]`. So the function works as intended. However, I would like to know how I could shorten this function using list comprehension. **If possible, can this function be defined and returned in a single line?**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve filtering in list comprehension:

```py
def unique_evens(lst):
    return [len(set(word.lower())) for word in lst if len(word) % 2 == 0]

print(unique_evens(['tifa', 'cloud', 'barret'])) # [4, 5]
```

Comment: I think the output for this function might be slightly different from the one I listed in my example. I noticed that for inputs like unique_evens(["Wooooool","Lesssss", 'uncopyrightable.']), your function would return [2, 16] instead of [3, 16] which was my output and the result I believe is right. Do you think you could show me why this is?

Comment: @Oliper - this solution produces [3,16] for the list you referenced in your comment.

Comment: oh I may have made an error. I'll double check my work.

Comment: If I wanted to differentiate upper and lowercase values in a string, how would I intergate this into the function? Like suppose I want to try unique_evens(['Aa','Baab','Cbac']) and return an output of [2,3,4]. I would just get rid of lower, right?

Comment: @Oliper Remove `.lower()`.